# Loading a matrix from a csv (dataframe) to R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have my data in this format in a csv

```
state1       state2       state3
  1             0            0
  1             0            0
  0             0            1
```

and I would like this in a matrix in R like this

```
1     0     0
1     0     0
0     0     1
```

I have tried loading the csv as a data frame and putting it into a matrix, but it does give the desired result. Using this code, I get this output

```
df <- read_csv('filepath')
m <- matrix(df)

matrix format output:

1     1     0
0     0     0
0     0     1
```

This essentially makes a column a row instead of maintain what was originally stored. I want the matrix to hold the same structure that was in my csv file.

Comment: use `as.matrix(df)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform `t()` the result:

```
m <- t(as.matrix(read_csv('filepath')))
m
## 1     0     0
## 1     0     0
## 0     0     1
```